# Multiple Selection In TableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I am trying to edit and **Select the Tableview Cell** So it's selecting the Cell But The problem is In my Cell there is One View is available. So when Its Highlight the cell Then **Red Color View** is disappearing from the cell.

So How I will show **red Color view** after selection of tableView

***Link to this Code is*** [https://github.com/anupgupta-arg/iOS-Swift-tableViewSelect](https://github.com/anupgupta-arg/iOS-Swift-tableViewSelect/blob/master/tableViewSelect/tableViewSelect/ViewController.swift)

[image]

Now My Cell Design is

[image]

Comment: Instead of using view, you can use background color for selected cell

Comment: @Anup Gupta: Can you show the design of your cell?

Comment: @iPeter check my cell Design

Comment: @Khushbu I don't want to change of cell color I just only want if I will select the cell then Red color view always show it's not hidden behind the highlighted cell.

Comment: @AnupGupta why you have taken this extra uiview for highlighted cell? Can you explain it?

Comment: @Khushbu I am not taking any extra highlighted it a default property of apple you can check in the **Message Application** in iPhone

Comment: @AnupGupta can you please show your tried code?

Comment: @Khushbu [gitHub] (https://github.com/anupgupta-arg/iOS-Swift-tableViewSelect/blob/master/tableViewSelect/tableViewSelect/ViewController.swift) this is the link you can check here

Comment: @AnupGupta write "cell.selectionStyle = .none" in cellForRowAt method of tableview. and add cell background color for selected row.

Comment: @Khushbu when I am writing this `cell.selectionStyle = .none` then i am **not able to select the cell**.

Comment: @Khushbu you can check my code I had tried all the possible case but nothing was working.

Comment: Can you show the configuration of this cell in storyboard, I mean the settings you do in the options panel or the code of this cell if it’s a custom subclass of UITableViewCell

Comment: @Pranshu you can Check this complete code on [GitHub] (https://github.com/anupgupta-arg/iOS-Swift-tableViewSelect/blob/master/tableViewSelect/tableViewSelect/ViewController.swift)

Comment: @AnupGupta please uncomment the code you have tried.

Comment: @Khushbu I had tried all the code one by one but no one is working so I commented all the unused the code. When you download and run the app then you will get more idea about the code because Many times I was changed StoryBoard, not only in Code.

Comment: You can try setting the `UITableViewCell` `selection` property to `none`.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using **UIImageView with solid red colour image** instead of the **UIView**.
See my sample code. I have not done much in code everything is achieved through storyboard. Please check the linked images to understand the solution.

[Prototype Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xtzG.png) It has a label, UIImage and UIView with background colour red. The UIImage I set to some image with solid colour.

With this my table view looks like:
[TableView without ant selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUpK5.png)

[TableView with selection]You can see that the UIImageView is not impacted by the cell selection and UIView is impacted.[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH7xK.png)

Comment: Yes, ImageView Will work perfectly I know this. but In I have a list of color which is display there so I was looking for the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method in your SimpleTableViewCell:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
          super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        centerView.backgroundColor = .red
      }
```

When a cell is selected in a tableview, it changes background color of all its subviews to clear color, that's why your red color is changed everytime.

This just resets it's color every-time that happens.

Use this instead if you have multiple views:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
          contentView.backgroundColor = .gray
      }
```

This doesn't call super so the problems doesn't arise.

Comment: Yes, That is really irritating me. Your answer is correct but if there is the different color of view at some position so how to handle that?

Comment: Do not call super's setSelected, and change the background color of contentView yourself whenever selection state is changed in this same method.

Answer (score 0):

Use [multipleSelectedBackgroundView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623275-multipleselectionbackgroundview) for selected state, and put your other view (red one) in contentView.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the selected color of the cell, then Try this

Objective-C:

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

Swift:

```
let bgColorView = UIView()
bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
```

Comment: I don't want to change of cell color I just only want if I will select the cell then Red color view always show it's not hidden behind the highlighted cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show any colour on selection of `TableViewCell`.
Then follow these steps:

1. Select your TableView Cell from storyboard
2. Go to attribute Inspector
3. select `None` option from selection.

[For storyboard reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iazk3.png)

Comment: If he will do this, that checkbox will not update